# How to make basic 2D flip-clock in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I saw a mobile game called Township. There was a flip-clock based animation in that game. I was wondering how to make that flip-clock in unity.

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: No Actually, I don't know where to start. I saw some video but it's not optimized.

Comment: Unfortunately questions asking for tutorials, books or any off site resources are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on stackoverflow. Try to follow one of the tutorials you found and work from there. If you are having trouble with a specific coding related problem while you do this you can post another question and people will gladly help you solve it.

Comment: Okay.....Because of I did not find any tutorials, I came here for seeking answers.